# How to to solve divide by zero error (NaN - Not a Number) in my formula in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a column with a formula which reads:

```
Utilisation (Excl. Time-off) = Utilisation_Excl_Timeoff[Billable Hours]/(Utilisation_Excl_Timeoff[Available Hours] - Utilisation_Excl_Timeoff[Timeoff Hours (Excl. Public)])
```

It gives me a "NaN" error in my calculated column for some of the cells due to divide by zero.

I would like to replace the `NaN` with a `0%` instead so that the column displays correctly in my matrix chart.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the `DIVIDE` function (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj677276.aspx).
This is a 'safe divide` function with the option to return an alternative value if the division returns an error.

-JP

Comment: Thanks @JanPieterPosthuma. It worked well with the DIVIDE function.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for solution in M, then add conditional column:
[image]

Set up `Otherwise` temporarily to **dividend** column, here I took `[Value]` column. After doing this change in editor `[Value]` to `[Value]/[Units]`. This returns `null` wherever Units is 0. You may change returned output to `0%` according to thy wish.

Alternatively, you can do it as well by adding this step:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Previous Step", "UnitPrice", each if [Units] = 0 then "0%" else [Value]/[Units])
```

Answer (score 0):

`IFERROR(value, value_if_error)` function can do this. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634765.aspx)

`Utilisation (Excl. Time-off) = IFERROR(Utilisation_Excl_Timeoff[Billable Hours]/(Utilisation_Excl_Timeoff[Available Hours] - Utilisation_Excl_Timeoff[Timeoff Hours (Excl. Public)]), 0)`

Comment: Hi, thanks user5226582 but it throws back an error "expressions that yield variant data-type cannot be used to define calculated columns" but the DIVIDE function worked well.

Comment: Corrected the answer for future reference.

Comment: Thanks @user5226582. It works that way too. Much appreciated.

Comment: I disagree with this answer. Divide by zero is easy to avoid with JP's answer using `DIVIDE` which will perform well. Catching errors does not perform well